# Stop Chrome from sending no cache no store header

Tags: asp.net, iis, caching

I have static content (icons etc...) served via `Asp.Net`

Every response gets caching added to it, like this:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(Now.AddMinute(30))
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(True)
```

When I browse from my office everything is fine

When one of the users browses from home, the icons are not cached. Which makes browsing very slow.

I have a log that shows the incoming requests, and the requests from this user have this header

```
"Cache-Control":"no-cache, no-store"
```

I don't know if that's the issue, and if yes, how can I solve it? Or can there be something else wrong?

Also, after setting the cache expiration, it seems that the `Response.Headers` are not affected. I don't see the caching info in the headers.

This is the header string. Not a word about caching.

```
{Server=Microsoft-IIS%2f10.0&HitID=9&X-AspNetMvc-Version=5.2}
```

Why are my Cache settings being ignored?

Comment: Any ideas anybody? I want to totally ignore cache headers in the request. only `asp.net` should decide when to cache, even i the request says no cache or whatever. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your IIS cache setting. The static file setting may not related with the Response.Cache.SetExpires method().

And you can also set the Cache-Control in iis. About how to set the Cache-Control you can refer to this link.

[Cache-Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/manually-override-cache-control-directives-using-application-request-routing#:%7E:text=%20Step%201%20-%20Configure%20cache%20control%20rules.,the%20cache%20control%20rules.%20Similar%20to...%20More)

Comment: Hi. The static file is definitely getting served via `asp.net`. I see it in my log which is managed via code. would it have been served via `IIS` directly, my code would not even know of the request and not log it.

Comment: My answer above already mentioned how to set the Cache-Control in iis.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Application Request Routing is not even installed on this server. So i don't think that's the issue. Also, this works well for most users from most places. only a few users are complaining about slowness. So i don't think its a server-wide setting

Comment: Also. The link you provided does not give enough flexibility. My asp.net code decides per file when to add caching and when not. So how do I ensure that the response comes back with correct caching regardless of the request? and regardless on which server the app is installed? Thanks.